# How to delete external folders containing SAS datasets, using SAS

Tags: sas

In the drive, I have folders (date wise) which contain 1 SAS file each. My expected thing is to keep ***only 13 months of data***(only 13 months folders) and delete any other older folder in the drive. Do we have a code for it or is there is anything something else to do this help?

Comment: Please show what you have attempted and you can be pointed in the right direction based on that.

Comment: There are numerous functions for file management. Review the documentation for FDELETE.  You may want to take a step back and think a little more about your *expected thing* which separates calendar grouped data into separate folders or data sets.  If you can add one more column 'month', all the data (likely the same structure) can be stacked and managed as a single data set and processed using `CLASS` `BY` and `WHERE` statements

Comment: Why do you have separate folders for each single dataset?  That seems silly.

Answer (score 2):

Use either the [`FDELETE`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245893.htm) or [`DELETE`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sclref/59578/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000143503.htm) to do this, another useful function to use is [`FEXIST`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000210817.htm) which checks if a file physically exists. The sas Documentation in the links above have good examples.

Example Deleteing a Directory:The folder won't be deleted if it is not empty

```
%let TargetPath=c:\data\temp\Folder;
FILENAME FMyRep "&TargetPath";
%LET rc=%SYSFUNC(FDELETE(FMyRep));
%PUT rc=&rc;
FILENAME FMyRep CLEAR;
```

Original post [here](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/SAS_Filesystem_Toolbox).

Answer (score 0):

The following macro will delete an entire folder and all subdirectories (recursively) - it does this by extracting the contents, and deleting all the files from the bottom upwards.

https://core.sasjs.io/mp__deletefolder_8sas.html

The test for it is here: https://core.sasjs.io/mp__deletefolder_8test_8sas_source.html